# Ошибка подключения к базе данных Firebird

Tags: python, firebird, база-данных

Создал базу данных и подключился к ней

```
import kinterbasdb  
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'test.db' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'")  
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(dsn='Asus:/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
```

Выдало ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "D:/connect.py", line 3, in <module>  
    conn=kinterbasdb.connect(dsn='Asus:/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kinterbasdb\__init__.py", line 478, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **keywords_args)  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kinterbasdb\__init__.py", line 641, in __init__  
    b.dsn, b.dpb, b.dialect, timeout  
OperationalError: (-902, 'isc_attach_database: \n  Unable to complete network request to host "Asus".\n  Failed to locate host machine.')
```

Предполагаю, что причина в dsn (не уверен в нем). Как узнать dsn, если причина в нем конечно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо было использовать следующий прием:

```
import kinterbasdb  
import os  
os.remove('D:/test.db')  
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'test.db' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'")  
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')  
con.close()  
conn.close()  
print "Connect succesfully"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to locate host machine.

Написано же всё.

Comment: @abg,  я и так понял, что причина в dsn. А как его узнать?